# kafka consumer not receiving message over remote

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi I'm new to kafka and I have a quick question.

I implemented a kafka producer and consumer
zookeeper and producer is running in another server (192.168.10.233)
Consumer is running in another server (192.168.10.234)
Both are locally connected

Problem is
Consumer get connected with producer but not listening any message but if I move this listening part to same server (192.168.10.233) , it is receiving the messages

this is my code for consumer

```
def listen(): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.10.233:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "groupId");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);

    println("calling ---- but yet to receive the message")

    consumer.subscribe(List("test"));
    while (true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(100);
      for (record <- records)
      println("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    }

  }
```

I also checked 192.168.10.233:9092 from outside ,weather the port is not blocked by anything.

Comment: I believe that there may be a problem of the offset. You can try to set the offset like: props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest"); If it works, you can tune that value

Comment: Yes I added offset but still no luck

Comment: which version of Apache Kafka are you using? 0.9 or 0.10? You should have the same version for you client API.

Comment: @NangSaigon not necessarily. Kafka is backwards compatible and new brokers can handle messages from older clients. But not vice versa

Comment: I'm using 0.10 version for both

Comment: Can you try and see if the messages are being received by console consumer on this remote machine ? It will give you idea if producer is not able to send any message to remote host hence client is not getting it or the problem lies with client.

Comment: The problem was with the producer. It was published to local only. I solved the problem. Thanks for your comments @Gondola_Ride

Comment: @Muhunthan Could you share what fixed your problem? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: @activelearner The producer publishing to the locale only (0.0.0.0:9092). you must change the  producer configuration to listen like 192.168.10.233:9092 and you must restart the producer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have to set `advertised.host.name` in your `kafka/config/server.properties` to a value that is routable from outside.

Comment: I added and restarted the kafka and the zookeeper but still not luck. Actually it gets connected but it doesn't receive any message

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ? I am facing the same problem. I am not able to get messages from Kafka setup in my QA env from my local development environment.

Comment: i am also facing same problem, i try all the things but did not run producer in remote server. if you have solution than please suggest me